# Maintaining consistency between Datastore and Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

If I have the following JPA Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Image {
   private String name;
   privaet Blobkey blobKey;
   .....
   .....
}
```

Let's say I then use the blobstore service to persist a blob, and then use the blobkey as the attribute for a new Entity, and then persist the entity.

If I later on decide to delete the blob using the blobstore service, do I have to update the entity manually to make the blobKey attribute null?

I guess my question in general is are the Datastore entries and the blobstore entities 'aware' of each other at all, or is it up to me to keep the consistency/integrity between those datastore entities and the blobstore entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blobstore and datastore are completely separate, so if you do delete the blob, you will need to null the blobkey. Of course, if you don't, it won't necessarily be a problem, since the blobkey will point to an non existing object. But the actual entity will keep the blobkey attribute.